# How to import local excel file into snowflake database table? I will need to do this daily

Tags: excel, import, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

All -

I've done some research, but I'm having trouble finding a clear answer.

Problem to solve for:   I have a dependency where a co-worker updates a local excel file, and I need the information in that file to be imported into a snowflake data table for analysis.

The data structure of the excel file will always be consistent, but I will need to import the new file daily into Snowflake, and it can have as many as 200+ rows every day.

I've attached screenshots of what the excel file structure is.  What is the most simple way to enable my co-worker or myself to update the snowflake database table with the new file every day?

The excel workbook will be 2 sheets.  I've attached the sample data below.  Please help :/

[image: Sheet 1 of Excel File]

[image: Sheet 2 of Excel File]

Answer (score 0):

I would likely create a little Python application that loads the Excel file into a Panda dataframe and then loads that dataframe to Snowflake. Something like this might work: [https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/…](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/%E2%80%A6). Once that script is written, you could schedule it to run every day or just manually run it every day.

Comment: Do you think that's the easiest pathway?   If that's the only way to get it done, I will explore it.

Comment: It'd be my preference, because Python is familiar for me, and this would take about 10 lines of code.